# Adding NSLayoutConstraints to UISegmentedControl causes UISegmentedControl to disappear

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, uisegmentedcontrol, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UISegmentedControl defined programmatically.

I am trying to add a layout constraint so that when my iPad rotates, the segmented control sizes correctly within the rotated view rather than spill off screen.

I apply the following constraint:

```
        streamSegmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let segmentedControlWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: streamSegmentedControl,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.containerView,
        attribute: .Width,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: -10.0)

    containerView.addConstraint(segmentedControlWidth)
```

My UIsegmentControl is defined as follows:

```
      streamSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Today's Events", "Past Events"])
    streamSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(-10,containerView.frame.size.height*0.3,containerView.frame.width+20,40)
    streamSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    streamScope = "today"
    streamSegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(segmentedControlFont as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
    streamSegmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromClass("background")
    streamSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.colorFromClass("default")


    streamSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "changeStreamScope:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    containerView.addSubview(streamTableView)
    containerView.addSubview(streamSegmentedControl)
```

I don't get an error, but at runtime, my segmented control disappears. Not sure what I am missing here as I've only done auto layout within storyboards in the past.

I only want to be able to adjust the width of the segmented control, so I assume I only need a single layout constraint.

Can anyone give me some direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add three constraints at least. Leading, top and trailing.
I am weak in swift but your constraints should look like.

```
let segmentedControlTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: streamSegmentedControl,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.containerView,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0)

let segmentedControlLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: streamSegmentedControl,
        attribute: .Leading,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.containerView,
        attribute: .Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0)

let segmentedControlTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: streamSegmentedControl,
        attribute: .Trailing,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.containerView,
        attribute: .Trailing,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0)

containerView.addConstraint(segmentedControlTop)
containerView.addConstraint(segmentedControlLeading)
containerView.addConstraint(segmentedControlTrailing)
```

If you want to keep a 5 point offset from superview, try playing with constant values of leading and trailing using 5 points.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if that made any difference though. I get the following run time error: The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint. When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.

Comment: Make sure you add segmented control in hierarchy before adding constraints

Comment: Thanks. It's added to the container view:    containerView.addSubview(streamSegmentedControl)